# Real analysis Limit of Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:R \longrightarrow R $ is a function such that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x,y \in R$.Prove that $f$ has a limit at 0 iff $f$ has a limit at every point $c$ in $R$.

So how would i prove that ?
I am thinking if $lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)$ exists then how would i proceed ?

any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists. We need to show that for $c\in\mathbb{R}$ arbitrary, also $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)$ exists.

We have
$$f(x)=f(x-c+c)=f(x-c)+f(c)$$

Letting $x\rightarrow c$ and setting $y=x-c$ we see that $y\rightarrow 0$, so the limit in question exists by assumption and equals

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)=f(c)+\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} f(y)$$

Comment: How would i do the other implication , or does it follow from that >

Comment: The other implication is clear: if it exists at *every* point $c$ then in particular at $c=0$.